# WSO2 APIM / WSO2 IS - Admin (super_admin) non lock feature

Tags: wso2, config, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 APIM 3.2.0 and WSO2 IS 5.11.0.

Is there a way to enable the admin (super_admin) non lock feature?

i.e. even if n attempts of wrong password is used for the admin account login, the admin account should not be locked.

These are the only configurations I could observe for super_admin which is mentioned in the below link
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-the-system-administrator/

Is this possible through deployment.toml file or other configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the `Internal/system` role to any user to avoid that user getting locked.

But need to keep in mind that this will allow brute-forcing the super admin password. Therefore, the super admin username should be an uncommon one.